# Why is SSH authentication failing when using the login password?

Tags: ssh, root

I am trying to login via ssh to a server with the root account (yes, I know, a bad idea; I'm just testing), but authentication keeps failing :

```
Feb 21 09:26:38 myserver sshd[4481]: Failed password for root from x.x.x.x port 60708 ssh2
```

When I connect to the server via ssh with another account and do `su -` to get root access, I enter the password and it works. How is it possible that the password won't work for SSH but works on local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most SSH servers by default doesn’t allow root login over SSH, you’ll need to change a line in the SSH server configuration to allow this.

On most systems, this is done by uncommenting the `PermitRootLogin yes` line in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, and restarting the SSH daemon.

Answer (score 0):

uncommenting the **PermitRootLogin** yes line in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, and restarting the SSH daemon.